# What is ?= in bash?

Tags: bash

Bash in Linux had special characters.
One of special characters is `?=`.
special characters  `?=` what does it signifies. 
Unable to understand these type of special characters.
The script is written like `6LBR?=../..`.

Comment: Can you post more of the script?

Comment: Can you please post some relevant lines from the script?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This looks like it's from some sort of Makefile rather than from a `bash` script.

`bash` does not have a `?=` operator, but `make` has (as an extension to [the POSIX standard for `make`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/make.html)).  It assigns a value to a variable if the variable is not yet defined.

Reference (GNU `make`): https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#index-_003f_003d

Reference (BSD `make`): http://man.openbsd.org/make#VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENTS

There are a number of other languages that also have the `?=` operator, but `bash` is not one of them.

Comment: In `bash`, `6LBR?=../..` would be taken as a glob, the first expansion of which would be taken as a command name, and the rest as its other arguments (or if the glob doesn't match, `6LBR?=../..` would be the command name). Per POSIX, the behaviour is unspecified allowing implementations to implement a special  `?=` operator for instance.

Comment: Makefile seems likely indeed: https://github.com/cetic/6lbr/blob/56f8407964377406e1d0210b0928024a9b870f22/examples/6lbr/plugins/lwm2m-client/Makefile